# Binary Search Tree with pointers in C

Tags: c

I'm new in C. My task is to implement Binary Search Tree. So, I'm really confused with pointers. Though, the concept is clear in trivial cases but using pointers in structures is confusing for me.

I have header

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_st {
int value;
struct node_st *leftchild;
struct node_st *rightchild;
} node;

typedef struct tree_st {
    int size;
    node root; 
} tree;  

extern void insert(tree *t, int value);
```

I want to implement insert. Here is my attempt

```
extern void insert(tree *t, int value) {

int size = t->size;

node insertNode;
node *toInsert = &insertNode; 
toInsert->value = value;                  
toInsert->leftchild = NULL;
toInsert->rightchild = NULL;

if(size == 0) {
    t->root = toInsert; 
    t->size++; 
} else {

    node *current; 
    current = t->root;                  

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

        if(current->value < value) {
            if(current->rightchild != NULL) {
                current = current->rightchild; 
            }
            else {
                current->rightchild = toInsert;
                t->size++; 
                break;      
            }
        } else if(current->value > value) {
            if(current->leftchild != NULL) {
                current = current->leftchild; 
            }
            else {
                current->leftchild = toInsert;
                t->size++; 
                break;      
            }
        } else {
            printf("The value has been already inserted"); 
        }
    }


}
}
```

I get the following error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In
>   function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**Questions & Problems:**

1. What that error means?
2. Are all pointers in the function correct?
3. Is it necessary to define root as a pointer in `struct node_st` at
   all?

Comment: No, you must malloc new structure.

Comment: Why do you need this extern?

Comment: Looks like you have no `main()` function.

Comment: OT: Seems you miss a `break` after the `printf`

Comment: OT: `for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {` could simply be `while(1) {`

Comment: @purec extern is just for calling the function from another file. It shouldn't cause any problems

Comment: @RingØ Right, I don't specify `main()` function. From the first sight it's weird

Answer (score 1):

`node insertNode;` is a local variable declared in the scope of the function `insert`.
If the function terminates, then the variable is lost.

You have to allocate a dynamic node, by `malloc`:

```
node *toInsert = malloc(sizeof(node ));
```

In the `struct tree_st`, the element root is not a pointer to a node, but it is a node itself.
This causes that the assignment `t->root = toInsert;` doesn't work, because `toInsert` is a pointer to a a node.

Change the data type `struct tree_st` to make it work. The element `root` should be a pointer to a node too:

```
typedef struct tree_st {
    int size;
    node *root; 
} tree;
```

Comment: I get incompatible types error by t->root = *toInsert;

Comment: Now it works but the error (mentioned above) is still present